# Работа с List<> в WCF-сервисе

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Service

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        Client GetClientById(string id);
        [OperationContract]
        void AddClient(Client client);
        [OperationContract]
        int Count();
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Client
    {
        private string id;
        private string name;

        [DataMember]
        public string ID { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    }

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        private List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();

        public Client GetClientById(string id)
        {
            foreach (var client in clients)
            {
                if(client.ID.Equals(id))
                    return client;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void AddClient(Client client)
        {
            clients.Add(client);
            Console.WriteLine("Clients count: {0}", clients.Count);
        }

        public int Count()
        {

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(clients.Count);
                return clients.ToArray().Length;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return clients;
        }
    }
```

После вызова метода `AddClient(Client client)` вызов метода `Count()` возвращает `0` (`try catch` не срабатывает) , при том, что метод `AddClient(...)` выводит в консоль `Clients count: 1` (независимо от того, сколько раз был вызван этот метод). Конечно, это не то, что мне нужно.

Мне нужно, чтобы после вызова метода `AddClient(...)` в список `clients` добавился экземпляр класса `Client` и можно было к нему обращаться из любого метода. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию создается отдельный экземпляр сервиса на каждую сессию. Наверное, это не вполне то, что вам нужно.

Для задания поведения сервиса существует атрибут [`ServiceBehavior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Вероятнее всего, вам понадобится [`InstanceContextMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx) - `Single`:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    // ...
}
```

PS чтобы не натыкаться на подобные "приколы" в дальнейшем - не забывайте всегда добавлять отладочную печать в конструктор, раз уж вы ее добавили во все остальные методы.

PPS Зачем делать `ToArray()` ради получения `Length`? У списков есть свойство `Count`.

И рассмотрите возможность перехода от списка к словарю (`Dictionary<string, Client>` - он лучше подойдет к вашей задаче).

Comment: По поводу ToArray() - это уже отдельная история. Спасибо, за ответ. Помогло!